# @click not working in google maps infowindow button

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

In my Vue app I show a Google Map with markers, which are retrieved from an API with Axios. When I click a marker, it shows a info window with a button, which has a `@click='show_details = !show_details'` to toggle an additional div with details. This is not working however and I don't know why. This is the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="map">
    <div class="google-map" id="map"></div>
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="visit-details" v-show="show_details">details</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Map',
  data(){
    return {
      lat: 54.6,
      lng: -2,
      show_details: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    renderMap(){
      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng },
        zoom: 6,
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 3
      })

      axios.get('https://bla.json')
        .then(res => {
          res.data.forEach(doc => {
            let contentString = "<div @click='show_details = !show_details'>details</div>";
            let visitLatLng = {lat: doc.latitude, lng: doc.longitude};
            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: visitLatLng,
              title: doc.ground,
              map: map
            })
            let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: contentString
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
          })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.renderMap()
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't know vue.js but it looks like it is the same issue explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23627538/1238965).

Comment: not sure if the @click="" is being compiled, if its being compiled then try @click.native="".

Comment: The @click.native doesn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: It seems it is not rendering, so maybe using https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps Infowindow is outside Vue.js scope ! Maybe not the most clean solution but you can use global function that will have reference to your Vue function like this :

```
window.myGlobalFunction = this.myVueFunction;
```

And in your InfoWindow content

```
"<div><a onclick='myGlobalFunction(" + someParam + ")'>Hello</a></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Create vue Infowindow content component, pass data, subscribe to events using $on, $mount vue component and inject element into infowindow. Fire vue infowindow component events using $emit.

InfoWindow.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <v-btn @click="selectLocation(item)">Select Location {{item.Name}}</v-btn>
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    name: 'infowindow',
    props: [ 
        'item',
    ],
    methods: {
        selectLocation(item) {
          // emit click action in infowindow
          this.$emit('action:selectedLocation', item);
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

And in the portion of the code that is required to create before opening the info-window:

```
...
import InfoWindowComponent from './InfoWindow.vue';
...

var InfoWindow = Vue.extend(InfoWindowComponent);
var instance = new InfoWindow({
    propsData: {
        item: item
    }
});

instance.$mount();

// parent subscribes to event from infowindow
instance.$on('action:selectedLocation', (item) => {
    // handle click action
});

var new_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: instance.$el,
});

new_infowindow.open(<map object>, <marker>);
```

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50197706/556649
- https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/